# Issue about Intellij IDEA with scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have a scala project but I don't know how to run it :
[image]

This is an java project and it has a button in main Method line:
[image]

my project  is this :
[image]

what should I do to find the button to run my scala program

there is no run button[image]

Comment: Can you state the version of Idea you have?

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot comment, I will write here: you must point the scala class and right click on it, and then you have the Run. In the pictures you are trying to run the java class

Comment: there is no have the Run ,i'm in scala Object to Right click .you can see the image

Comment: as @Karthikeyan mentioned do u have installed the plug in ?

Answer (score 1):

Few things:
a) Check to make sure, your source directory is included as module
   i.e. File > Project Structure. In the attachment below you see my modules
[image]

b) Check to make sure you have included your scala library, I believe you have this setup.
[image]

c) Last resort, see if you can add your object as Application
i.e. Run > Edit Configuration & the following[image]

Hope this helps, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You need a scala plugin to run a scala file. And find more at the [get started documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-running-your-scala-application.html?origin=old_help) of idea.